# Python NLS http encoding

Tags: python, utf-8, python-requests, python-unicode

I am trying to do some integration testing on our web pages using National Language Support (NLS).  For example, I try posting a page with form containing the value "Fréd" for the first_name.

To do this I set up Python 3.7.3 with

```
import request
```

And then do requests.post with the data {'first_name': "Fr\u00E9d"}

At some point the UTF-8 str is translated to bytes, but those are not translated to the accent e code.  I dug through the code and it boils down to this test case:

```
>>> "Fr\u00E9d"
'Fréd'
>>> "Fr\u00E9d".encode("utf-8")
b'Fr\xc3\xa9d'
```

The w3schools list \xc3 as LATIN CAPITAL LETTER A WITH TILDE and \xa9 as COPYRIGHT SIGN.

Assuming this is not a problem with Python encoding, how should I be coding these NLS characters in Python.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: There are no UTF-8 strings in Python. `"Fréd"` and `"Fr\u00E9d"` are Unicode strings (they are really *the same string value*, just inserted differently). `b'Fr\xc3\xa9d'` is a byte string with the UTF-8 encoding of the same name.

Comment: But, as I understand the definition of Unicode, it is a codeset, and it is coded as either UTF-8, UTF-16, or UTF-32.  The Python str built-in has a method called encode, that encodes the data into a byte-string.  What I need to know is how to  specify the string so that the .encode("utf-8") in the Request class encodes the proper utf-8 bytes.  

BTW, I have bypassed the issue by specifying my own byte-string, but that is at best a bypass that bytes me latter when I get the response that has the processed values as a string.

My problem here is that when I do code the

Comment: What you say is correct. And `b'Fr\xc3\xa9d'` is the correct UTF-8 representation of `'Fréd'`. Since you mention the A-tilde/copyright characters: Do not confuse `b'Fr\xc3\xa9d'` with `'Fr\xc3\xa9d'` (or `'FrÃ©d'`), which is mojibake (gibberish) caused by interpreting the UTF-8 bytes as if they were Latin-1.

Comment: In essence: either you see a problem where there isn't one, or I don't understand your question.

Comment: According to several authoritative web sites (i.e. https://www.w3schools.com/charsets/ref_utf_latin1_supplement.asp), é should be encoded as hex \xE9.  \xC3 is a Ã, and \xA9 is ©.  &Atilde;&copy; is what gets presented in the generated HTML as well.  My question is how to code a str literal that generates various NLS character, é being the example I am presenting.  I have bypassed the issue by coding a byte string with a \xe9 and my web site properly handles this (and the reflected text is indeed showing é.

Comment: I'm not suggesting a problem, just trying to figure out how in Python to do this.  Our web site supports users with 11 different languages, and it would be expedient to be able to test the data entry forms to see that they can indeed handle NLS.

Comment: In Unicode, "é" has the codepoint `E9`, often represented as U+00E9. This number is what you use in numeric HTML entities etc. Its UTF-8 encoding is `C3 A9`, which is `b'\xc3\xa9'` as a Python literal. This is how a character is written to disk in a text file. If you use the Latin-1 (ISO-8859-1) character set instead of UTF-8, then "é" encodes to `E9`, which happens to be equal to the Unicode codepoint. But Latin 1 can only represent a small subset of Unicode.

Answer (score 0):

I think I am beginning to understand.

So when I send in an  with the value "Fréd", my browser is encoding this as (according to firefox debugger) Fr%E9d.  The web server then appears to recognize this as Fréd.

"Fr\u00E9d" gets translated to  b'Fr\xc3\xa9d' by the .encode("utf-8") in requests/models.py.  Problem is that our form appears to only accept-charset="ISO-8859-1".

I am guessing that the python Requests package shouldn't blindly do the conversion.  But that is getting a bit beyond the scope of this question.

Thanks for clearing this up.